# HTML + CSS infinite scrolling background: Flicker on Safari at repeat

Tags: html, css, safari

I'm creating a scene with a bunch of scrolling layers (foreground, midground, background etc...) but annoyingly I get a flicker on Safari (14.0.3) when the animation restarts. This doesn't occur on Chrome or Firefox.

I've created a minimum reproducible example here:

https://brendon.github.io/safari_flicker/index.html

Here's the code:

```css
.animation {
  position: relative;
  height: 395px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#1b9dd9, #00b6ed 44%, #ffe56c 75%);
}

.animation .scrollingAnimation {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.animation .scrollingAnimation:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
}

.animation .foreground:before {
  /* Dimensions: */
  /* width: 1696px; */
  /* height: 74px; */
  min-width: 6784px;
  background-image: url("https://brendon.github.io/safari_flicker/foreground.png");
  background-position: left bottom -11px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: auto 74px;
  transform: translateX(-1696px);
  animation: foreground 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes foreground {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-1696px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-3392px);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="animation">
    <div class="foreground scrollingAnimation"></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is a video of the issue:

https://github.com/brendon/safari_flicker/raw/main/flicker_video.mp4

I've tried many things to get rid of the issue. It seems to sometimes go away depending on the window width, but I'm looking for a solid solution :D

The issue also exists on iOS Safari.

I should mention that I don't want to animate the `background-position` property as this causes performance problems and isn't accelerated by the GPU.

Comment: You need to add some kind of code to your question that will help reproduce the issue.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I can see the whole animation flickering on restarting on Microsoft edge - Android ![Check screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElWbx.jpg)

Comment: I'm facing the same issue here. Did you ever find the solution?

Comment: Check out my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67634347/129798 It was annoying that I couldn't do it another way, but GSAP isn't so bad to use and is far more flexible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using GSAP [`fromTo()`](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/GSAP/gsap.fromTo()) to manage the transition work instead of relying on the CSS animation:

```html
<div class="foreground scrollingAnimation"><div></div></div>
```

```js
gsap.fromTo(
  '.foreground > div',
  { xPercent: -25 },
  { xPercent: -50, duration: 10, repeat: -1, ease: 'none' }
)
```

```css
.scrollingAnimation {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;

  > div {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
  }
}

.foreground {
  > div {
    width: calc(1696px * 4);

    background: {
      image: url("https://brendon.github.io/safari_flicker/foreground.png");
      position: left bottom;
      repeat: repeat-x;
      size: auto 74px;
    }
  }
}
```

It breaks down on very wide screens, but really, if you're rocking a 6000px wide window, good luck to you sir.

The way GSAP animates is that it changes the `translateX` value via javascript during a `requestAnimationFrame` (I think) so it's nice and smooth, and the flicker problem doesn't exist in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using 2 elments with the same image and animation, and offsetting - using delay - the first elements animation by `-duration / 2` ?

The idea being that at all times there's one of them on screen and any render delay shouldn't be visible.

See below, I'm animating two pseudo elements.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.animation, .foreground {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
}

.foreground:before, .foreground:after {
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 50vmin;
}

.foreground {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.foreground:before {
  content: 'A';
  background: red;
  
  animation: 10s linear -5s infinite foreground;
}

.foreground:after {
  content: 'B';
  background: blue;
  
  animation: 10s linear 0s infinite foreground;
}

@keyframes foreground {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="animation">
    <div class="foreground scrollingAnimation"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: That sounds like a positive direction. Just before I begin trying it out, would this cause issues on very wide screens? I'm thinking probably not, as long as both elements were at least 100% wide and had their background-image repeating.

Comment: @BrendonMuir Yeah I was going to make an edit to add that as a caveat. It will only fix your issue if you can guarantee that an element is completely offscreen when it restarts the animation loop. In this case, so long as the width of the animating elements are more than 100% of the container, then it will be fine.

Comment: Given it's a repeating pattern it needs to be both at least 100% as wide as the container, but also a multiple of the width of the image.

Comment: @BrendonMuir The image makes it more complicated but you can isolate that as a concern of the element and not the animation. `TranslateX` with percentages works on the elements width (not the container width), so if the elements width is an exact multiple of your image width then the animation takes care of itself. You will have to decide what maximum screen width you want to support and have your element width be more than that.

Comment: I see :) My main aim is for this to support arbitrary screen widths but if that's not possible then this should be an ok compromise :)

Comment: @BrendonMuir how'd you go?

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try this out, but will do today. I was also waiting to see if anyone had any other ideas :) I'm wondering if I should file it as a bug with Safari?

Comment: It worked to some extent but I think due to timing issues, there are small gaps between the two pseudo elements. These gaps go away when trying to observe the elements with the inspector (and the node highlighting tool)! So close! This doesn't matter on my example layer, but the others are continuous repeating patterns so the gap is noticeable.

Comment: Giving each of the different layers (foreground, mid ground etc...) its own named animation (Even though it was the same) seemed to solve the gap problem. Very strange! I'll do some tests tomorrow but I think your solution works :)

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately the gap still occurs. I think it's quite hard to have the animations start exactly at the same time so depending on cpu load the slight offset causes a gap.